# Split message into several (at least two) in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

My Apache Camel's route at some point generates a list of objects.

I have another route that expects one object as a message as well as certain object-specific headers and records it to database.

What would be the best way to configure Camel route so that list is:

- split into individual objects as Camel messages
- some Camel message headers added to each split message
- and each message goes in certain route?

At the moment I have a need to split list just of two messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can use Camel's [splitter EIP](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) to split the messages up into as many messages as you want. If you pass a list into a splitter it will automatically split the list by easy element in the lest. If the default splitting tools aren't enough you can write a custom split bean that splits the message in any way you want.

```
from(START)
 .split(). method(SplitBean.class, "splitMessage")
 .to(FINISH);
```

Adding headers to a message is also pretty simple. If all the messages have the same header you can just tack on something like this:

```
.setHeader("cool", simple("true", Boolean.class))
```

after you split.

Routing each message to a different route is also easy using camel [dynamic routing](http://camel.apache.org/dynamic-router.html).

Comment: What about split() without a parameter? Can it happen?

Comment: yes, if your message body containers a List/array or something with an iterator then camel will automatically split that list into it's individual elements.

Comment: @david after splitting, how can we combine those individual to a single one, like, can we put these individual to a list?

Comment: I'll be honest it's been 5+ years since I touched Apache Camel and I'm sure much has changed since then. Last I remember you can use the [aggregate](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/eips/aggregate-eip.html) pattern to turn multiple messages into a single one. As for how to do that I have long forgotten.